Can angled pistons manipulate the directions of gas forces?
Say we have a rectangular tube, and inside that tube is a right angled prism with a sliding gas tight fit. The prism is 1 inch tall, 1 inch long, and 1 in inch thick.

If we charge the left side of the tube with 100 psi, then the flat face of the prism would experience exactly 100 pounds of force pushing it to the right.
The angled side however, I'm not so sure about. I think it would experience roughly 70 pounds of force pushing it left and 70 pounds of force pushing it down.
The surface area of the angled side is sqrt(2), which is roughly 1.4. When we multiple the pressure by the surface area we get (1.4 * 100) roughly 140 pounds of force. But that force is angled at 45 degrees. So if we break it down to the component vectors then half of the force is pushing the prism down into the floor of the tube and the other half of the force is pushing the prism to the left. So in effect, only 70 pounds of pressure is pushing the prism left.
Is that the correct interpretation of the forces?

Well after thinking about it... intuitively, I must be wrong. Otherwise if you just held a prism in your hand it would experience a net force and move across your hand. The left and right faces are exposed to the same pressure, so if there were a net diff in forces then it would just start to accelerate and that's clearly not a known property of prisms

You’ve gone incorrect with how you broke down the component vectors of the force. A 45 degree angle won’t split the force in half vertically and horizontally, it will split it by cos(45)=1/sqrt(2) which exactly cancels the previous factor of sqrt(2) that you had.
